# Accessing the JQuery object an event is called on, inside a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, this

Inside a function I create this link using JQuery:

```
var link = $('<a />')
  .attr('href', 'linktarget.htm')
  .text('Link');
link.on('mouseover', showDefectMapIcon(this, row.id));
```

When the user hovers the link, an image should be replaced:

```
function showDefectMapIcon(el, id) {
  console.log(el);
  $(el).next('span.info').find('img')
    .attr('src', '/defectmap.php?id='+ id);
}
```

However it does not work, because el is referencing to the td element the surrounding function is called on, not the a element, as it should.

I also tried `showDefectMapIcon(link, row.id)` and `showDefectMapIcon.call(link, this, row.id)`

How can I pass the `$('<a />')` object to the function in such way, that I can work with it inside the function with `$(el).next('span.info')` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, in your case the callback(`showDefectMapIcon`) is called when your code is executed on the event... you are invoking the function `showDefectMapIcon` instead of passing it as a callback

```
link.on('mouseover', function () {
    showDefectMapIcon(this, row.id)
});
```